# Anaconda install package without administrator rights

Tags: anaconda, access-denied, admin-rights

I have a python installation in a directory where I don't have admin rights or write permission. I am using Python 3.6.5 and conda 4.5.4 on windows 7.

When  run `conda install -c conda-forge python-fmask` I get the following error message:

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::pytables-3.4.3-py36he6f6034_1'.

PermissionError(13, 'Access denied')
```

The folders `conda-meta` and `pkgs` are located in a directory where I have write permission. There are hardlinks to these folders in the Anaconda installation directories. In which directories does conda need permissions in order to install packages?

Answer (score 9):

I was running into this problem. My solution is to reinstall Anaconda and when selecting installation type, select "Just Me" so that the installation is in your user directory where you have full access rights.

Perhaps this is not the most pleasant solution, as it requires reconfiguring your Anaconda setup, but it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try asking the administrator to let users have control over the folder where anaconda is installed. This is a one-time thing and is easier than asking to run as admin every time you have to install a package.

Comment: I also asked the administrator to add control over the Python folder